# Javascript Expected expression and missing case or statement errors

Tags: javascript

I have the two errors - "Expected expression" (3rd line) and "missing case or statement error" (35th line). Here is my code:

```js
var days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30];

function month(number)
{
    var res = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < number; i++)
        res += days[i];  
        
        return res;  
}

function counter()
{
    var date = new Date();

    if((date.getFullYear() % 4) == 0 && (date.getFullYear() % 100) != 0)
        days[1] = 29;

    return (month(date.getMonth()) += date.getDate());
}

function season(day)
{
    if (day > month(2) + 20 && day <= month(5) + 21)
        return 0;
    else if (day > month(5) + 21 && day <= month(8) + 22)
        return 1;
    else if (day > month(8) + 22 && day <= month(11) + 21)
        return 2;

    return 3;
}

switch(season(counter()))
{
    case 0:
        document.getElementById("im").src = "wiosna.jpg";
        break;

    case 1:
        document.getElementById("im").src = "lato.jpg";
        break;

    case 2:
        document.getElementById("im").src = "jesień.jpg";
        break;

    case 3:
        document.getElementById("im").src = "zima.jpg";
        break;

    default:
        break;

}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work.. When i delete the first function then it points the next function. Any ideas? Thanks for help!

Comment: This is wrong ` return (month(date.getMonth()) += date.getDate());`, which is like `Math.round(a) += 3` which is not a valid expression. You should remove the `=` symbol

Comment: I suggest you to please use curly braces as a general habit while programming wherever possible, though its not mandatory for one liner statements but it is a nice practice to have when your code grows and it also improves readability and has several other advantages :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting

```
var ret = month(date.getMonth());
ret += date.getDate();
return ret
```

for

```
return (month(date.getMonth()) += date.getDate());
```

to prevent `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` error

```js
var days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30];

function month(number)
{
    var res = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < number; i++)
        res += days[i];  
        
        return res;  
}

function counter()
{
    var date = new Date();

    if((date.getFullYear() % 4) == 0 && (date.getFullYear() % 100) != 0)
        days[1] = 29;
  
    var ret = month(date.getMonth());
    ret += date.getDate();
    return ret;
}

function season(day)
{
    if (day > month(2) + 20 && day <= month(5) + 21)
        return 0;
    else if (day > month(5) + 21 && day <= month(8) + 22)
        return 1;
    else if (day > month(8) + 22 && day <= month(11) + 21)
        return 2;

    return 3;
}

switch(season(counter()))
{
    case 0:
        document.getElementById("im").textContent = "wiosna.jpg";
        break;

    case 1:
        document.getElementById("im").textContent = "lato.jpg";
        break;

    case 2:
        document.getElementById("im").textContent = "jesień.jpg";
        break;

    case 3:
        document.getElementById("im").textContent = "zima.jpg";
        break;

    default:
        break;

}
```

```html
<div id="im"></div>
```